# Extracting value of a node when another element is embedded within

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to process an XML document from another system, and the XML that I am getting is in pseudo-HTML that I need to convert to HTML.

**Sample XML:**

```
<DOC>
<Paragraph>This text is <bold>bold</bold> and this text is not.</Paragraph>
</DOC>
```

**Required Output:**

```
<BODY>
<P>This text is <b>bold</b> and this is not.</P>
</BODY>
```

Using node() value I am able to get the value of  node before  tag (This text is ), but I am not able to write a template hat would process part of the  node before  tag, process  tag, and then return to remainder of the  value.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DOC">
    <BODY><xsl:apply-templates/></BODY>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Paragraph">
    <P><xsl:apply-templates/></P>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bold">
    <b><xsl:apply-templates/></b>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

What did you try? Should not be much more complicated than

```
<xsl:template match="DOC">
    <BODY><xsl:apply-templates/></BODY>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Paragraph">
    <P><xsl:apply-templates/></P>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bold">
    <b><xsl:apply-templates/></b>
</xsl:template>
```